# Is there a fallback for the method Application.ShowMe from Office-Automation?

Tags: vba, ms-word, office-automation

The method Application.ShowMe from Office-Automation is deprecated.
With the last Microsoft Update the call of this method results with 0x800A1088.

Is there a fallback for Application.ShowMe() ? or is it sufficient to set the property "Visible" to True ?

thanks

I just set the property "Visible" to True.

Comment: This should be sufficient. If not, you should write what you expect / need and what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

To make the Word application visible you need set the [Application.Visible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.visible) property to true.

```
Application.Visible = True
```

There is no other fallback mechanism. That is enough for making Word visible.

Also you may find the [Window.Activate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.window.activate) method helpful. It activates the specified window. The `Window` object is a member of the `Windows` collection. The `Windows` collection for the `Application` object contains all the windows in the application, whereas the `Windows` collection for the `Document` object contains only the windows that display the specified document.

Use `Windows(Index)`, where `Index` is the window name or the index number, to return a single `Window` object. For example, the following example maximizes the `Document1` window:

```
Windows("Document1").WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.   

I have developed some codelines many years ago and was surprised that the method `Application.ShowMe` has been deprecated by Microsoft.

It is sufficient to set the property `Visible = True`, but what was the purpose of the method `ShowMe` ?
Unfortunatly, there ist no old documention of the Application-Object online.